# Angular - Date format with 01 Sep, 2021

Tags: angular, date, angular-pipe

How to get date format 01 Sep, 2021 in angular application.

Looking for pipe format example to get this date format on the web page.

Comment: You can check the documentation https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DatePipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) with following format 'dd MMM, yyyy'

`dd` - Numeric: 2 digits + zero padded

`MMM` - Abbreviated

`YYYY` - Numeric: 4 digits or more + zero padded

```
{{ date | date: 'dd MMM, yyyy' }}
```

> Output

> 01 Sep, 2021